# get name of the pod consuming highest cpu using kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to get the pod name with highest CPU utilization using kubectl command.
Able to retrieve list using following command but unable to write a jsonpath query to fetch the name of first pod from the output.
Appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks!

```
kubectl top pod POD_NAME --sort-by=cpu
```

Answer (score 4):

`kubectl top` doesn't appear to enable `--output` formatting and so no JSON and thus no JSONPath :-(

You can:

```sh
kubectl top pod \
--sort-by=cpu \
--no-headers \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
| head -n 1
```

I think it would be useful to support `--output` for all `kubectl` commands and you may wish to submit a feature request for this.

> **NOTE** Hmmm [`kubectl top` output format options](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/753)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to manage getting first pod Name and details with head argument added. Looking for an option to get only Name from the result.

Comment: @haridurgempudi I'd reckon you could add this:  `| cut -d " " -f 1`  to the end of whole command to get only the name of the `Pod`.

Comment: thanks for the response. got it with the command- 
kubectl top pod -n qa --sort-by=cpu --no-headers | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 1